# List All Enabled Network Adapters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7 and I'm trying to list all ENABLED network adapters not only connected
i have this code but it only show connected adapters

```
procedure GetAdapters;
var
oBindObj : IDispatch;
oNetAdapters,oNetAdapter,
odnsAddr,oWMIService : OleVariant;
i ,iValue : longword;
oEnum : IEnumvariant;
oCtx : IBindCtx;
oMk : IMoniker;
sFileObj : widestring;
begin
Form1.sComboBox1.Items.Clear;
sFileObj := 'winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2';

OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0,oCtx));
OleCheck(MkParseDisplayNameEx(oCtx,PWideChar(sFileObj),i,oMk));
OleCheck(oMk.BindToObject(oCtx,nil,IUnknown,oBindObj));
oWMIService := oBindObj;

oNetAdapters := oWMIService.ExecQuery('Select * from ' +
'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ' + 'where IPEnabled=TRUE');

oEnum := IUnknown(oNetAdapters._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;

while oEnum.Next(1,oNetAdapter,iValue) = 0 do begin
try
Form1.sCombobox1.Items.Add(oNetAdapter.Caption);
except
end;

oNetAdapter := Unassigned;
end;

odnsAddr := Unassigned;
oNetAdapters := Unassigned;
oWMIService := Unassigned;
end;
```

when i remove this `+ 'where IPEnabled=TRUE'` from code it show me about 17 adapters but i only need to show adapters as it listed in Windows Device Manager under Network Adapters

Comment: Try to get list of `Win32_NetworkAdapter`s with `PhysicalAdapter == True` and while iterating fetch their configuration through [this relationship](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee692585.atnbas04_big%28l=en-us%29.gif) ([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692585.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks.. It's working but it list all Physical Adapters (Enabled and Disabled)  is there a way to filter it and show only Enabled adapters?

Comment: Why are you using WMI for this? Have a look at `GetAdaptersInfo()` and `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead. Those are native functions that enumerate network adapters directly.

Comment: Try this WQL sentence to list only the enabled adapters `SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE PhysicalAdapter = True AND MACAddress IS NOT NULL AND AdapterType IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know those functions and when i tried it now it's not available in Delphi 7 can you show me how to call it and use it in Delphi 7?

Comment: @RRUZ It works Great that's what i was looking for.. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: @RRUZ Where do I run this query?

Comment: @Mohamad make a procedure and call it GetAdapters same code in my question and change the query to RRUZ query.. that's it